# CSS variable won't get set | Electron

Tags: javascript, css, electron

I'm currently having an issue with CSS variables not being set, I'm using electron and im trying to set it like this:

```js
  for (let Button of ThemeButtons){
    Button.addEventListener("click", e =>{
      let Color = Button.style.backgroundColor;
      let root = document.documentElement

      console.log(Color)
      root.style.setProperty('--CurrentA', Color);
      root.style.setProperty('--CurrentB', Color);
      root.style.setProperty('--CurrentC', Color);
    });
  }
```

And i've my variables defined like so:

```css
:root {
  --red:#923333;
  --orange:#d68a00;
  --green: #0d840d;
  --blue: #1c4a90;
  --purple: #6a1d8a;
  --dark: #313131;
  --gray: rgb(68, 68, 68);
  --light: #b7b7b7;

  --CurrentC: rgb(85, 85, 85);
  --currentA: rgb(68, 68, 68);
  --currentB: rgb(53, 53, 53);
}
```

The color is printed, but the variable is not being set.
I've seen 'BlinkFeatures' and i've enabled those too, i still can't get it to work. Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a problem of css specificity. :root points to the document trees root (HTML tag) and so does `document.documentElement` except :root has higher specificity (as seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root))

To solve this problem you should probably set the variable overrides to e.g. body tag or change `:root {}` to `html {}`

Comment: That makes sense, I've tried that with both body and html but it didn't work unfortunately, is there any way I can debug it?

Comment: My bad, it does work except it doesn't change the CSS document, just the style in the HTML tag of body. How can i make it change the style in the internal CSS?

Comment: Did you keep the css in the :root but change the js reference to body? Inline defined css variables should override css ones if they have more specificity than css ones. Editing the css files trough javascript is not possible

Comment: I put the css in ```html {}``` when changing the style, it does not do anything, the other elements colors remain the same. The refference in javascript is: ```document.documentelement```, In the console an inline css is made but nothing happens beyond that

Comment: Put the javascript to document.body and it might work

Comment: @Nipatiittii I've done some de-bugging and noticed the variable is getting set in an inline style for html, but the inline style doesn't override the internal style for some reason.

The internal style will always be chosen for it's variables instead of the inline style. Any ideas as to why?

(Also, i've tried the document.body thing instead and same issue as above)